# Do not think I came to destroy the Law or the Prophets but to fulfil them?

Tags: matthew, law

Jesus did not do away with any thing of the Old Testament:

> Do not think I came to destroy the law or the Prophets but to fulfill them. - [Matthew 5: 17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205%3A17&version=NIV)

For that means to celebrate the holy days and not the man made ones celebrate: Passover not Easter celebrate, the Feast of Unleavened Bread, follow the Ten Commandments. So what does that mean? Also at the end of Mathew he says “teach them to observe all thing I have commanded them.”

Comment: It's not clear what answer you expect to get here. "For that means... what does that mean?"

Comment: I don’t think this is a question . If you want to make a statement you are allowed to simply raise a valid question and then provide an answer also. That’s how other do it on occasion. But I understand the temptation. I have done it before myself haha

Comment: We fulfill the law by being crucified with Christ, so that we take on his nature. We do not try to fulfill the law through our own strength to help Christ out or add to his righteousness. All of our righteousness comes from Christ’s obedience. Not only us, but no one else can fulfill the law after Christ, as the temple is destroyed, there are no more sacrifices, etc. it’s over. No one else can keep the law.

Comment: He fulfilled the Passover, for instance, by passing over from death to (eternal) life. Whatever ultimate spiritual realities were symbolized by various biblical passages, He came to fulfill them.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus fulfilled the law by living in obedience to the Father. He wasn't that interested in the letter of the law, especially all the onerous man-inspired interpretations. He even broke the Sabbath law, seemingly with great relish and encouraged others to as well. "Take up your bed and walk."
He was mostly concerned about the heart. The best way to fulfill the law is to follow Jesus' example, love God and your neighbor as yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I am more inclined to translate the verse as: "*Do not think I came to destroy the law or the Prophets but to **complete** ([**pléroó**](https://biblehub.com/greek/4137.htm)) them*". In other words, the moral Law of the Prophets was a foundation but not yet the entire or complete way to salvation (because the moral law alone can result in spiritual 'death', such as burning in 'hell' if you get angry at a sinner or at your brother who sins).

As for those parts of Law Jesus said he would not abolish, this is explained in Matthew 19:16-22:

> And behold, one came to Him and said, “Teacher, what good thing shall
> I do that I may obtain eternal life?” 17 And He said to him, “Why are
> you asking Me about what is good? There is only One who is good; but
> if you wish to enter into life, keep the commandments.” 18 He said to
> Him, **“Which ones?”** And Jesus said, “You shall not commit murder;
> You shall not commit adultery; You shall not steal; You shall not bear
> false witness; 19 Honor your father and mother, and You shall love
> your neighbor as yourself.” 20 The young man said to Him, “All these
> things I have kept; what am I still lacking?” 21 Jesus said to him,
> “If you wish to be complete, go and sell your possessions and give to
> the poor, and you shall have treasure in heaven; and come, follow Me.”
> 22 But when the young man heard this statement, he went away grieved;
> for he was one who owned much property.”  (The parallel passage is
> found in Mark 10:17-22 and Luke 18:18-23, listed at end of the
> article).

Therefore, it appears Jesus was referring to the core fundamentals of the Law rather than the more superficial and dispensable tenants of what is now called Judaic or Talmudic Law.

Since Jesus said: "*a time is coming when you will worship the Father neither on this mountain nor in Jerusalem... God is spirit and his worshipers must worship in the Spirit and in truth.*" (John 4.21), whether you worship on Saturday, Sunday, Easter or Passover is irrelevant to his Way.